Is it reasonable to think that the Earth could be gone because of climate change and global warming by 2069?
In my fictional dystopic post-apocalyptic world, the Earth is still "livable" as of 2084, but in 2069 something happened (as in something "magical") that will eventually make the human race go extinct.
Eventually, people realize that they are the cause (wars, pollution, blah blah) but the consequences of their actions were more mystical than an actual destruction of the planet.
Nevertheless, I´d like to show coherence in terms of timeline, so... do you think we´ll be able to destroy our planet by that date? Or am I risking it too much?
I chose that year because I didn´t want to bother to come up with new technology and a future human society, when literally nothing of that will be further depicted in the series (because they will need to start from scratch, as almost always happens in any apocalypse).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What do you mean with "destroy our planet"? Only the biosphere, making it unlivable for only us or the whole planet like turning it into dust?

You need to explain what you want a bit more clearly. You want something "magical" with "mystical" consequences. OK, make it magical/mystical. Maybe they dug up a relic that Tutankhamen-cursed the entire planet. Why bring in global warming? If you actually want something natural, not magical, take your pick of global warming, rampant pollution, Covid Mark 2 (This Time It's Deadly), nuclear winter, accidentally leaked bio/chemical/unspecified WMD... Make the story good and no one will care if the timeframe is off by a few years.

By "destroying our planet" I guess I meant only the biosphere, as in, it won´t be able for us humans to survive on Earth for more than 50 years since 2069.

Totally agree with what you´re saying. In fact, my story is full fantasy/ sci-fi, so it clearly doesn´t make any sense to try to give it an understandable context in terms of how people are treating the planet.

For future reference, this is a poor type of question to ask on Stack Exchange (which is why you see that comment by the automated Community BOT). From our perspective, whether or not a consequence can happen by a specific date is irrelevant. You tell us what you want to happen and by when and (assuming you've met the rules in [tour], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask] and [ask]) we can help you rationalize that world rule.

This (human activity unleashes a supernatural threat which works as a fictional proxy for the human fear of runaway self-destruction) is the central plot of Godzilla. That's not a bad thing. But it might give you some ideas.

It's really far too late to edit this question, but for for future reference, I think we missed an opportunity to tackle an interesting worldbuilding query here.  Everyone has been answering your marquee question: destruction by natural disaster. Fairly mundane, and I'm sure that as such, this should be closed as a duplicate. Yet no one has addressed the metaphysics. You mention, without focusing on, "something magical" or "something mystical" as potentially being at the root of this. To be frank, the natural disaster is just so much narrative necessity. We missed a deep dive (cont)

(cont) into a deeper, more profound, level of worldbuilding here.

To make a point, I've been hearing environmentalists, climatologists, and ecological activists claim the Earth's climate would be "irreversibly damaged in the next 3-5 years" regularly since the late 1970s. Despite the overwhelming evidence that humanity is hard-pressed to permanently hurt the planet, the masses have marched to the drum for three generations now. We're being chastised today by children who think the destruction is actually imminent. Is your date believable? Absolutely. Many people would think you're egregiously optimistic. Is it realistic? Not historically.

Unlikely.
For humanity, complete extinction is difficult, unless perhaps a fast acting, hard to detect virus (either natural or engineered) that has no vaccine and no treatment, that has an almost 100% fatality rate. Even then some could find ways to elude it.
A War, even a global nuclear war, is unlikely to make the human race 100% extinct, as there would likely be survivors in some corner of the Earth that could carry on (in a shelter, cave or other protected area). There are some analysts say that war could cause population levels to drastically decline to pre-medieval levels.
Indeed there is evidence that the human population during the Toba Catastrophe got reduced to only 1000 human individuals just 70k years ago - yet those individuals managed to keep the human race going and expand to where it is today.
As for Climate Change and Global Warming the following is expected by 2070:

sea level rise by 54 inches
average Earth temperature to rise by 3º, with a 7.5º increase in some areas of human habitation from today's levels

It is predicted these effects would adversely affect the health and survivability of 3.5 billion people in the world, and there would be significant unrest and possibly millions of deaths due to failed crops, loss of farmland and collapsed ecosystems. Still, currently there are 8 billion people in the world.
So humanity would likely not experience complete extinction directly due to Climate Change. The real danger would be the steady reduction of human population levels due to hunger, famine and conflict to a small amount of people (say a billion or less), small enough for a calamity to wipe the survivors out (for instance a War, or an engineered virus). However this is unlikely to occur prior to your 2069 date.

Nitpick - way more effective is a slow acting virus.  The reason Ebola isn't as big a problem as it could be is that it kills its hosts very quickly.  What you want is a near-100% fatality rate and a very, very long infectious period where it's otherwise dormant.

Id add the non-zero risk of AI going destructively off-the rails.
2069 is long enough time for the AI to either wipe us out or help us solve global warming, making OP's scenario impossible one way or another. The idea that by 2069 technology and society would not change much is incorrect, the pace of change is accelerating, so 2069 will be as advanced and alien to us as we would be to a Medieval person.

To expand on jdunlop's idea, an air spreading virus that has a 3-4 week period with minimal symptoms and highly contagious during that time but then have a 24 hour with 100% fatality would be very effective in reducing the human population. The air spreading is critical. If it needed bodily fluids to spread, the spread will be very slow, and quarantine would work to stop it.

@jdunlop even with the 'best' virus for the job imaginable it will still miss the lost tribes with no outside contact in the amazon and elsewhere.

@GoingDurden "the pace of change is accelerating" just come from the 1980's have you? It's a nice myth but it's really not, innovation (aka fashions) don't count, the pace of actual technology and science has if anything been slowing down, in some areas and ways has even been stagnating for some time now.

Instead of climate change, how about a teratogen or reproductive toxin?
While the "within 50 years from 2069" timeframe given in the comments is a lot easier than humans being completely gone before 2069 (though it would still be very challenging. Mostly destroying human civilization would be easier) the options we have related to climate change specifically are almost nonexistent.
There are a few mechanisms that might possibly amplify the magnitude of climate change beyond what might be survivable for humans, but most of them operate on the scale of millennia, not a few decades. For example, the "clathrate gun" hypothesis is sometimes touted in the media as a possible cause for abrupt, catastrophic climate change, but the current scientific consensus is that it is very unlikely gas clathrates in permafrost will make any detectable impact during this century (see the Future Projections section of the Executive Summary of Chapter 5 of the IPCC Sixth Assessment Report Working Group 1 Full Report, which also includes a few other feedbacks). This, of course, does not prevent it from being played up in fiction, and a few post-apocalyptic works do use exactly that.
On the other hand, a 50 year timeframe is one or two generations, and it's possible for a significant reduction in the human population over that time. For example, a highly effective and widespread reproductive toxin might have cumulative effects after decades of exposure (say, 2050 to 2070) by which time there is a catastrophic decline in human fertility. You would need an eventually almost total loss of fertility for it to completely wipe out humanity after two generations, though a smaller effect might be enough to destroy human society and technological progression, which seems to be enough for what you're after (not coming up with new technology or society). There are, of course, no known toxins that fit that criteria... If you actually wanted one that's confirmed to exist, that would be impossible because if we had one, we would be as dead as we would be in your story, obviously.

You first need to answer the question (1), how long would it take for every human to have been in contact with every human, within the standard 6 degrees of separation.
Then you need a pathogen that can infect a human, and be almost guaranteed 100% passed to all other humans that come into contact with the infected human, and stay withing the human, long enough to wait until ALL other humans are infected (answer of Question 1) So no-one has the need or desire to find a cure.(and likely passes down to offspring)
Then once infected, some cause (Question 2), triggers an internal mutation that kills the host faster than a cure can be made.
Typical pathogens might not be able to achieve this, but, mystical means may have been responsible, maybe for the trigger.
One plausible way, as global warming thaws the icecaps, a pathogen is released that humans are infected with. but its internal structure is benign. All humans slowly contract this (for the time period required from answer 1) Once the oceans reach a particular temperature, or the planet or some normal state of the world (hayfever like? see Q2.) , the pathogen triggers its next stage, and within days everyone is sick and weeks, dead.
If I understood your timeline, in 2069 people started dying or are dead, and by 2084 some new race arrives at earth, finding the pre-existing humans to be all dead.
The little information I can find for a 7 degree timeline for 99.9%, would be 10 years as rough estimates. So the pathogen needs to be 'found' in 2059.

"You first need to answer .. how long would it take for every human to have been in contact with every human" allowing for 'lost tribes' in the amazon, and the handful of science outposts that only see visitors and staffing changeover once or twice a year (that if the timing of the disaster happens just right just won't get the next changeover, and the same for the several extremely remote inhabited islands that see practically no visitors year on year)? You'll never get them all, a virulent enough pathogen has a burnout rate that will leave pockets untouched, even if only the lost tribes.
